# IND-CPA security scheme

Tags: provable-security, pseudo-random-function, chosen-plaintext-attack

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CPA Secure Chosen plaintext scheme](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5250/cpa-secure-chosen-plaintext-scheme)

The example for IND-CPA secure schemes given is generally:

for a random r,

$Enc_k(m) =(r|| E_k(r)$ $XOR$ $m)$ where $E$ is a $PRF$

But does the role of r and k really matter--i.e. isn't this equally secure?

$Enc_k(m) =(r|| E_r(k)$ $XOR$ $m)$ ?